# Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()in /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/canonical/canonical/edit/tab/header.phtml on line 79

Tags: php, magento

what should i do to fix this error ?

> ERR (3): Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/canonical/canonical/edit/tab/header.phtml on line 79

```
    <?php if ( Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('admin/global_search') ): ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Search</legend>
        <span id="global_search_indicator" class="autocomplete-indicator" style="display: none">
            <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/ajax-loader.gif') ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->__('Loading...') ?>" class="v-middle"/>
        </span>
        <?php $defSearch = $this->__('Global Record Search') ?>
        <input id="global_search" name="query" type="text" class="input-text" value="<?php if(!empty($query)): ?><?php echo $query ?><?php else: ?><?php echo $defSearch ?><?php endif ?>" onfocus="if(this.value=='<?php echo $defSearch ?>')this.value=''; " onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='<?php echo $defSearch ?>';" />
        <div id="global_search_autocomplete" class="autocomplete"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            new Ajax.Autocompleter(
                'global_search',
                'global_search_autocomplete',
                '<?php echo $this->getUrl('adminhtml/index/globalSearch') ?>',

                {
                    paramName:"query",
                    minChars:2,
                    indicator:"global_search_indicator",
                    updateElement:getSelectionId,
                    evalJSON:'force'
                }
            );
            function getSelectionId(li) {
                location.href = li.getAttribute('url');
            }

        </script>
    </fieldset>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
</div>
<?php  if(Mage::getStoreConfig('advanced/modules_disable_output/FME_Canonical')==0) : ?>
<?php   
        $product_id =  Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('id');            
        $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
         $selected = $_product->getData('fme_canonicalurl'); 
        $catIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();
            foreach ($catIds as $key ) 
            {
                $catCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
                     ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $key);
                foreach($catCollection as $cat)
                        {
                                $dat[] = $cat->getId();
                        }  
            }   
?>

<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function () { 
    if(categories = document.getElementById("fme_canonicalurl"))   
    {
    var categories = document.getElementById("fme_canonicalurl");
    var newOption = document.createElement('option');
    newOption.text = "<?php echo  $_product->getUrlPath() ?>";
    newOption.setAttribute('value', "<?php echo  $_product->getUrlPath() ?>");
    categories.appendChild(newOption);
    <?php 

    foreach ($dat as $value ) {
        echo "var newOption = document.createElement('option');";
        $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($value);
         $url = $_product->getUrlPath($_category); ?>
        newOption.text = "<?php echo $url  ?>" ;
        newOption.setAttribute('value',  '<?php echo $url ?>');
        categories.appendChild(newOption);
        <?php 
    }
    ?>
    function setSelectedIndex(s, v) {
            for ( var i = 0; i < s.options.length; i++ ) {
            if ( s.options[i].value == v ) {
                s.selectedIndex = i;
                return;
                }
                    }
                }
        setSelectedIndex(categories,"<?php echo $selected?>");  
    }    
}
```

Comment: Hard to say. You don't show how `$dat` is created, so it's pretty hard to know how to fix it.

Comment: Sorry for that ! Please copy :

Comment: You are the Boss Robbie Averill, successfully done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're pushing data into the `$dat` array from within a loop, but you didn't initialize it first. In the case where no results are looped and no data is pushed to `$dat`, it is then undefined when you try and loop over `$dat` later on.

Initialize it first:

```
$catIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();
$dat = array();
foreach ($catIds as $key) {  
    $catCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $key);

    foreach ($catCollection as $cat) {
        $dat[] = $cat->getId();
    }
}
```